# I am trying to install a package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install a php packege in laravel. After install with composer getting issue trait class does not found.

Step one:

```
{
    "require": {
        "avalara/avataxclient": "*"
    }
}
```

After removing this line  `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`
My controller script is

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class AvaController extends Controller
{
 // Include the AvaTaxClient library
use Avalara\AvaTaxClient;

// Create a new client
public function avatax(){
$client = new Avalara\AvaTaxClient('phpTestApp', '1.0', 'localhost', 'sandbox');
$client->withSecurity('', '');

// If I am debugging, I can call 'Ping' to see if I am connected to the server
$p = $client->ping();
echo('<h2>Ping</h2>');
echo('<pre>' . json_encode($p, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . '</pre>');
if ($p->authenticated == true) {
    echo '<p>Authenticated!</p>';
}

// Create a simple transaction for $100 using the fluent transaction builder
$tb = new Avalara\TransactionBuilder($client, "DEFAULT", Avalara\DocumentType::C_SALESINVOICE, 'ABC');
$t = $tb->withAddress('SingleLocation', '123 Main Street', null, null, 'Irvine', 'CA', '92615', 'US')
    ->withLine(100.0, 1, null, "P0000000")
    ->create();
echo('<h2>Transaction #1</h2>');
echo('<pre>' . json_encode($t, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . '</pre>');

// Now, let's create a more complex transaction!
$tb = new Avalara\TransactionBuilder($client, "DEFAULT", Avalara\DocumentType::C_SALESINVOICE, 'ABC');
$t = $tb->withAddress('ShipFrom', '123 Main Street', null, null, 'Irvine', 'CA', '92615', 'US')
    ->withAddress('ShipTo', '100 Ravine Lane', null, null, 'Bainbridge Island', 'WA', '98110', 'US')
    ->withLine(100.0, 1, null, "P0000000")
    ->withLine(1234.56, 1, null, "P0000000")
    ->withExemptLine(50.0, null, "NT")
    ->withLine(2000.0, 1, null, "P0000000")
    ->withLineAddress(Avalara\TransactionAddressType::C_SHIPFROM, "123 Main Street", null, null, "Irvine", "CA", "92615", "US")
    ->withLineAddress(Avalara\TransactionAddressType::C_SHIPTO, "1500 Broadway", null, null, "New York", "NY", "10019", "US")
    ->withLine(50.0, 1, null, "FR010000")
    ->create();
echo('<h2>Transaction #2</h2>');
echo('<pre>' . json_encode($t, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . '</pre>');
}
}
```

When I try to run this script, I get this error:

> (1/1) FatalErrorException Trait
>   'App\Http\Controllers\Avalara\AvaTaxClient' not found
>
> in AvaController.php line 8

please let me know If I am missing anything here.
Thanks

Comment: `use Avalara\AvaTaxClient;` should probably be outside of your class? And I hope those are not your real credentials

Comment: make sure to `use Avalara\AvaTaxClient;`

Comment: Two things; 
1. your `use` statement to include `AvaTaxClient` should be outside the class definition, for example under `use IllimunateHttp\Request;`

2. did you run `composer install` after adding the requirement in `composer.json`?

Comment: If you installing package by writing package name in composer.json file then you should do `composer update` first and then `composer install`.

Comment: @@ use Avalara\AvaTaxClient outside class same error,Please help

Comment: – Dilip Hirapara @I am getting same issue

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Comment: Samuel Liew@ I have done this@please let me know how can I resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to set every "Avalara" keyword with \ backslash

```
$client = new \Avalara\AvaTaxClient('phpTestApp', '1.0', 'localhost', 'sandbox');
$tb = new \Avalara\TransactionBuilder($client, "DEFAULT", \Avalara\DocumentType::C_SALESINVOICE, 'ABC');

->withLineAddress(\Avalara\TransactionAddressType::C_SHIPFROM, "123 Main Street", null, null, "Irvine", "CA", "92615", "US")
->withLineAddress(\Avalara\TransactionAddressType::C_SHIPTO, "1500 Broadway", null, null, "New York", "NY", "10019", "US")
```